# Simplicial orbit realization functor.

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, adjoint-functors

In their paper, *[Singular functors and realization functors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/1385725884900167)*, Dwyer and Kan define a "realization functor"  $\mathbf{O}\otimes - \colon \mathbf{S}^{\mathbf{O}^{op}}\to \mathbf M$ for a tensored and cotensored simplicial category $\mathbf M$ and a simplicial subcategory $\mathbf{O\hookrightarrow M}$ satisfying certain conditions which (I think) are not directly relevant to my question. Their definition is as follows:
[image]
I find the definition of the first morphism unclear, I don't see how $X_g$ is defined, since we are not taking $O_e\otimes \Delta[n]$ to be in $\mathbf O$ necessarily, and further, it doesn't seem to have the correct variance. Am I missing something?

Comment: Everything is simplicially enriched, right? My guess is that one should interpret $g\colon O_e\otimes\Delta[n]\to O_{e'}$ as an $n$-simplex of of $\underline{\mathbf{O}}(O_e,O_{e'})$, which is a simplicial set by definition. $X$ is supposed to be a simplicial functor, so $X(g)$ is an $n$-simplex of $\underline{\mathbf{SSet}}(X(O_e),X(O_{e'}))$ and the $n$-simplices of the latter are exactly maps of simplicial sets from $X(O_e)\times\Delta[n]\to O_{e'}$.

Comment: This seems to be some kind of simplicially enriched coend, which would make more sense if the direction of the first morphism is reversed.

Comment: @VincentBoelens, it looks like you're right, I somehow missed that $X$ was supposed to be a simplicial functor. If you want to, you can answer the question and I will accept it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first arrow should go from the right to the left. As remarked in the comments, this would give you a simplicially enriched coend.

Since $\mathbf{M}$ is tensored over $\mathbf{S}$, we have an isomorphism of simplicial sets
$$\mathbf{S}(\Delta[n],\mathbf{O}(O_e,O_{e'}))\cong \mathbf{O}(\Delta[n]\otimes O_e,O_{e'}).$$
So after taking $0$-simplices we see that a morphism $\Delta[n]\otimes O_e\to O_{e'}$ is the same as an $n$-simplex of $\mathbf{O}(O_e,O_{e'}) = \mathbf{O}^{\mathrm{op}}(O_{e'},O_e)$. Since $X$ is a (contravariant) simplicially enriched functor, it comes equipped with a map of simplicial sets $X\colon \mathbf{O}^{\mathrm{op}}(O_{e'},O_{e})\to \mathbf{S}(XO_{e'},XO_{e})$. The right hand side has $n$-simplices $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbf{S}(\Delta[n]\times XO_{e'},XO_{e})$. Thus, if $g\colon \Delta[n]\otimes O_e\to O_{e'}$ is an $n$-simplex of the left hand side, it gets sent to a map of simplicial sets $X_g\colon \Delta[n]\times XO_{e'}\to XO_{e}$.